# Which is the correct spelling: “fairy” or “faerie”?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, orthography

*Fairy* vs. *faerie* — which is the correct spelling?

Comment: Note that you will sometimes see the spelling *faërie*, to indicate it is meant to be pronounced with three syllables. For example, in poetry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As others have noted, *fairy* is the standard modern spelling, and *faerie* is a pseudo-archaism.

However, in some contexts there is now a semantic distinction between the two spellings! In particular, *fairy tales* and the associated idea of *fairies* typically refer to the genre of folk stories printed by the Brothers Grimm, then sweetened and popularized for modern audiences by Disney et al. *Faerie stories*, on the other hand, are stories about the *fae*: otherworldly, unpredictable, and dangerous creatures who appear in the folk-tales and myths of England and Ireland. In origin, of course, the *fairies* and the *fae* are one and the same, but the connotations and usage of the words today are headed in opposite directions.

A Google image search for [fairy](http://www.google.com/search?q=fairy&hl=en&prmd=ivnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=zsS2TeyxEIbPiALs1v0U&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=799) vs. [faerie](http://www.google.com/search?q=faerie&hl=en&prmd=ivnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=18S2TbOtFJHXiALKtYQm&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBMQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=799) shows a lot of overlap, but some very significant differences in tone and content between the two terms. Note that the search for "fairy" turns up a number of simple cartoon drawings and classical, idealized figures, while the search for "faerie" has a higher proportion of non-human and sexualized figures.

Answer (score 10):

Here we have a difference between sources: the *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports *faerie* (and *faery*) as ***“late 16th century (introduced by Spenser): pseudoarchaic variant of fairy”***. On the other hand, [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=faerie) has ***“ supernatural kingdom, "Elfland," by late 14th century, from Old French”***.

At least one available data point weighs, to me, in favour of *etymonline* (and thus against *NOAD*): *[Oberon, the faery prince: A masqve of prince Henries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon,_the_Faery_Prince)* was first published in 1616.

---

Going further, I looked at the French *féerie*, which derives from Old French *faerie* (circa 1188), itself from *fae* (modern writing: *fée*) (1140), itself from Latin *fata* (deities of destiny, or [Parcae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcae)). This is unlike *fate* itself, which comes from Latin *fatum, -a*, (“oracle, prediction”).

So, *fairy, fay, faeries, farye* and *the Fates* comes from the same Latin root *fata*, while *fate* itself comes from the different *fatum, -a*. Blows my mind!

Comment: +1, great answer.  The OED has the same theory as NOAD: Spencer in the late 16th century (1590), though, so I'm inclined against the etymonline theory.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the former is correct in modern usage, a descendant of the latter which is seemingly from Old French / Middle English.

From The free dictionary:

> For '[Fairy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fairy)'
>
> [Middle English fairie, fairyland, enchanted being, from Old French faerie, from fae, fairy, from Vulgar Latin Fta, goddess of fate, from Latin ftum, fate; see fate.]
>
> For '[Faerie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/faerie)':
>
> [Middle English faierie, fairie; see fairy.]

Comment: That's right - "fairy" is the standard modern spelling. The spelling *faerie* is sometimes seen, usually by people trying to add a historical or [poetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faerie_Queene) air to their writing.

Comment: @psmears: Yeah, I wanted to get to the point, poetic archaism aside. A rare one, I would guess.

Comment: @psmears or by people trying to sell arty rubbish in their shoppe

Answer (score 3):

The current usage difference is that fairy is the mythical creature, and faerie is the world of fairies. However, Brian Froud, who is considered to be the main authority of fairies, nearly always uses the archaic form faery or faeries. I personally like to use the old form, but my spell-checker doesn't like it, ha.

Anyway, not a linguist here, but rather a fairy enthusiast, who's read the etymology of the word a number of times in my studies.

Answer (score 0):

As reported from the NOAD, *faerie* (or *faery*) is the archaic or literary word for *fairyland*, or *fairy*.

As for the origin, it reports it is late 16th century (introduced by Spenser), and it is a pseudo-archaic variant of *fairy*.

Comment: I think NOAD has it wrong… see my answer for an earlier example

Answer (score -2):

Fairy is most definitely the more modern, Disney-ised version of the derivatives of the ancient word Fae, which represented all folk in the realm of nature spirits.  Faery and Faerie keep this ancient derivative and are used by Faery historians and artists who connect deeply with all aspects of Faery.  Fairy is more commonly used by Disney and other sources who turn the realm of Fae into complete fantasy and sometimes nonsensical, childish beings who "only exist in the imagination of the child".  Fairy tends to be used to represent modern constructs of Faery, who are often in pink, sparkly clothing with Tiaras and other human attire.  Faery represents the light and the dark of the realm of Faery.  Not only the dark, as some others present on the internet as the difference of spellings.  Faerie or Faery keep the ancient connection to the word Fae, as the modern Faerie world is strongly connected to the ancient.  Where as the modern "Fairy" world seems to be completely removed from its ancestry and brought into a more consumer based modern world.

Comment: You do know that 'faery' is also complete fantasy?