# Monsters! another question about what-was-it-then

Tags: synonyms, history, loanwords

Etymonline has the original meaning of [monster](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=monster) as

```
c.1300, "malformed animal, creature afflicted with a birth defect"
```

but I am curious to know the term used at that time -- and even earlier -- for (one of) its current meaning(s): "mythological or fantastic creature: dragon, fairy, brownie, griffin, etc.".

The same entry suggests *aglæca* as a possibility.  Any further support (or conversely, examples showing this use to be poetic or otherwise unusual) would be most welcome.

Also of interest would be terms in other Indo-European languages (esp. Latin, Greek, the Germanic languages, and the Indic languages) before, say, 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: ***Fayre beast*** (or *fearie*).

> In Araby is a kynde of beast that some men call Garsantes, that is a fayre beast (*The voiage and trauaile of Syr Iohn Maundeville, knight*; 1568) (cited for example in *[The Giraffe in History and Art](http://www.archive.org/stream/giraffeinhistory27lauf/giraffeinhistory27lauf_djvu.txt)*,  Berthold Laufer, 1928).

---

Longer answer: *beast* seemed obvious from the start, and [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beast) marks it as “early 13th century”, which fits. I spent some time looking for the right adjective, even though I had spent some time earlier this morning in writing a [somewhat comprehensive etymology of *fairy* and related words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/which-is-the-correct-spelling-fairy-vs-faerie/22681#22681). It then dawned on me, and Google Books confirmed at least one use (but they don't have many books that old, so it's hard to gather statistics).

Comment: That's exactly it.  Thanks for the supporting quote, too.

Comment: Although the copy I found of _Syr Iohn_ has them as "spotted" beasts rather than "fay" beasts.

Answer (score 1):

*Fifel*, *þyrs*, and *eoten* are good Old English words that typically mean 'giant' (or 'demon' in the case of *þyrs*) but also mean 'monster' in a generic sense.  It looks like none of these words particularly survived into modern English. Etymonline has mod. E. *ettin* for the last, but that's not exactly conversational.  Beowulf has *fifelcynn* 'monster-kind'.

*Wight* has the sense of 'monster', especially of supernatural origin, in addition to the broader meaning 'animal'.

Besides *wight* there are other creature-words which may be modified with *fay* or other such words as appropriate for the time period (*unsælige*, *eadily*, *eldritch*, etc.), especially *deer* and *beast* in any of their various spellings.